# Validation error on nested writable serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a writable nested serializer like this -

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = publicAddress
        fields = "__all__"


class customerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publicAdd = AddressSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
        model = customerMaster
        fields = ['id','publicAdd']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Address = validated_data.pop('publicAdd')
        customer = customerMaster.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for addres in Address:
            publicAddress.objects.create(customer=customer, **addres)
        return customer
```

this all works fine until I apply validation such as

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = publicAddress
        fields = "__all__"
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=publicAddress.objects.all(),
                fields=['customer', 'someValue']
            )
        ]
```

And defining

```
read_only_fields = ('customer',)
```

in AddressSerializer won't help either.

Now it throws an error such as **cust** field is always required and to send the cust value via api.

Any help on how to validate this without an error?

Comment: The UniqueTogetherValidation class always imposes an implicit constraint that all the fields it applies to are always treated as required. Fields with default values are an exception to this as they always supply a value even when omitted from user input. (copied)
https://coderedirect.com/questions/625774/drf-3-0-uniquetogethervalidator-with-a-read-only-field

Answer (score 2):

`customer` is a read-only field. it means `DRF` only uses it for responses after creating your object. but in `UniqueTogetherValidator` it needs data before creating it.

As `DRF` says in documentation:

> The `UniqueTogetherValidator` class always imposes an implicit constraint that all the fields it applies to are always treated as required. Fields with **default** values are an exception to this as they always supply a value even when omitted from user input.

So you need to handle it manually:

```
class customerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publicAdd = AddressSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = customerMaster
        fields = ['id','publicAdd']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Address = validated_data.pop('publicAdd')
        customer = customerMaster.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for addres in Address:
           publicAddress.objects.create(customer=customer, **addres)
        return customer

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # customer is not in attrs because it's read-only
        # Maybe you need to add context data to your serializer or get it somehow you know
        object_exists = publicAddress.objects.filter(
            customer=your_customer, someValue=attrs["someValue"]
        ).exists()
        if object_exists:
            raise serializer.ValidationError("Duplicate object")
        return attrs
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, I was checking read_only_field for update method, but there it again asked for custumer data.  I just read documentation and found that validators (this way) enforces fields to be required always. Now I will have to write a custom validation either in views or validate method.

Comment: Found your updated answer now.